# Generic string encoder in C#

Tags: c#

What I need is very simple, but before I reinvent the wheel, I would like to know if something similar exist in the framework already.

I would like to encode (and decode) strings from a predefined characters table. I have many strings that contains few characters. Here is a string I would like to encode:

cn=1;pl=23;vf=3;vv=0

This string size is 20 chars, so 20 bytes.

In the string, I only use the following characters: cn=1;p23vf0

A total of 11 characters. So each character can be encoded with 4 bits only isn't ? Reducing the total amount of bytes used to 10.

Is there any existing method in .NET that can take a string in parameter and the reference table array and return the encoded bytes ?

char[] reference = "cn=1;p23vf0".ToCharArray();
string input = "cn=1;pl=23;vf=3;vv=0";

byte[] encoded = someClass.Encode(input, reference);
string decoded = someClass.Decode(encoded, reference);

Assert.AreEqual(input, decoded);

Answer (score 2):

Any compression algorithm uses [Huffman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_encoding).  Which is basically what you are looking for here.  That encoding isn't exposed as a class separately, it is part of the algorithm of the DeflateStream and GZipStream classes.  Which is what you ought to use, as long as your strings are a reasonable size.  If they are short then there isn't any point in encoding them.

Answer (score 2):

Interresting question... There isn't anything built in the framework, but it can be done for example like this:

```
public static byte[] Encode(string input, string reference) {
  int size = 1;
  while ((1 << ++size) < reference.Length);
  byte[] result = new byte[(size * input.Length + 7) / 8];
  new BitArray(
    input
    .Select(c => {
      int index = reference.IndexOf(c);
      return Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(i => (index & (1 << i)) != 0);
    })
    .SelectMany(a => a)
    .ToArray()
  ).CopyTo(result, 0);
  return result;
}

public static string Decode(byte[] encoded, int length, string reference) {
  int size = 1;
  while ((1 << ++size) < reference.Length);
  return new String(
    new BitArray(encoded)
      .Cast<bool>()
      .Take(length * size)
      .Select((b, i) => new { Index = i / size, Bit = b })
      .GroupBy(g => g.Index)
      .Select(g => reference[g.Select((b, i) => (b.Bit ? 1 : 0) << i).Sum()])
      .ToArray()
  );
}
```

The code is a bit complicated, but that is because it works with any number of bits per character, not just four.

You encode the string like in your question, except the string contains *twelve* different characters, not eleven:

```
string reference = "cn=1;pl23vf0";
string input = "cn=1;pl=23;vf=3;vv=0";

byte[] encoded = Encode(input, reference);
```

To decode the string you also need the length of the original string, as that is impossible to tell from the length of the encoded data:

```
string decoded = Decode(encoded, input.Length, reference);
```

(Alternatively to supplying the length you could of course introduce an EOF character, or a padding character similar to how base64 pads the data.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no out-of-the-box class that does exactly this, but it's not too hard using the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class of .NET.
Once you have a bit-array, you can convert it to a string, or a packed byte representation.

```
// modify this as appropriate to divide your original input string...
public IEnumerable<string> Divide( string s )
{ 
    for( int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2 )
        yield return s.Substring( i, 2 );
}

public IEnumerable<bool> AsBoolArray( byte b )
{
    var i = 4; // assume we only want 4-bits
    while( i-- > 0 )
    {
        yield return (b & 0x01) != 0;
        b >>= 1;
    }
}

// define your own mapping table...
var mappingTable = 
  new Dictionary<string,int>() { {"cn", 1}, {"pl",23}, {"vf",3}, {"vv",0} /*...*/ };
var originalString = "cncnvfvvplvvplpl";

// encode the data by mapping each string to the dictionary...
var encodedData = DivideString( originalString ).Select( s => mappingTable[s] );
// then convert into a bitVector based on the boolean representation of each value...
// The AsBoolArray() method return the 4-bit encoded bool[] for each value
var packedBitVector = 
  new BitArray( encodedData.Select( x => AsBoolArray(x) ).ToArray() );
// you can use BitArray.CopyTo() to get the representation out as a packed int[]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to minimize size of string it's better to use `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` here. It's very simple and will likely to compress your string much more than 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that built into the Base Class Library. You will have to build your own.

Take a look at the [Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class from System.Text - some elements may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(VS.71).aspx) class be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CrytpAPI.  here is a good example, [including](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/encrypting-decrypting-string/) the methods to Encrypt and Decrypt a string.  I don't think it will "compress" your data for you, though.